# Ionic SocialSharing with pdf file for whatsapp

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am using pdfMaker to create an object of type Document, I would like to send this file to a contact I have saved on Whatsapp, it would be something similar to using the `shareViaWhatsAppToReceiver` function using `SocialSharing`.

The file's attachment would already come in the message.

```
   this.socialSharing.shareViaWhatsAppToReceiver(`+55 ${contact.phone}`, `PDF`,
      null, this.pdfObj).then(async () => {
        const toast = await this._toast.create({
          message: 'Send success.',
          duration: 3000
        });
      });
```

The way I am doing above does not work, I would like to send the document directly as a parameter so that the message on Whatsapp is attached.

Comment: Hi Luiz did you find a solution for this.. I'm saving the PDF file in the device storage and now I'm trying to send it to Whatsapp...

Comment: shareViaWhatsAppToReceiver constructor having image option only.

Comment: Try using share method of socialSharing object.